# Plotting Y error bar using my current script

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, import, errorbar

```
import os
from PIL import Image as PImage
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import chisquare


# Read in csv file
# File: https://github.com/mGalarnyk/Python_Tutorials/blob/master/Python_Basics/Linear_Regression/linear.csv
raw_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Aidan\Desktop\NEW TASK\Amos_2001_4p2_APD_CONC_Fig2C_OC.csv")

# Removes rows with NaN in them
filtered_data = raw_data[~np.isnan(raw_data["y"])] 


x_y = np.array(filtered_data)

x, y, y_err = x_y[:,0], x_y[:,1], x_y[:,2]


# Reshaping
x, y = x.reshape(-1,1), y.reshape(-1, 1)

# Linear Regression Object 
lin_regression = LinearRegression()

# Fitting linear model to the data
lin_regression.fit(x,y)

# Get slope of fitted line
m = lin_regression.coef_

# Get y-Intercept of the Line
b = lin_regression.intercept_

# Get Predictions for original x values
# you can also get predictions for new data
predictions = lin_regression.predict(x)
chi= chisquare(predictions, y)

# following slope intercept form 
print ("formula: y = {0}x + {1}".format(m, b)) 
print(chi)

# Plot the Original Model (Black) and Predictions (Blue)
plt.scatter(x, y,  color='black')
plt.plot(x, predictions, color='blue',linewidth=3)
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=y_err, fmt='o', capsize=4, color='black')
plt.show()
```

> Imported csv data:
>
> 1.01214,0.3609367,-0.01214
>
> 1.992202,0.341559,0.007798
>
> 2.995016,0.3510846,0.004984
>
> 3.974359,0.3405953,0.025641
>
> 4.976273,0.3612314,0.023727
>
> 5.954718,0.3618527,0.045282
>
> 6.984058,0.3536173,0.015942
>
> 7.962502,0.3542386,0.037498
>
> 8.967653,0.3348767,0.032347
>
> 9.969748,0.3532908,0.030252

Error:

> runfile('C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3/temp.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Aidan/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 15, in 
>       filtered_data = raw_data[~np.isnan(raw_data["y"])]
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2685, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_column(key)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2692, in _getitem_column
>       return self._get_item_cache(key)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 2486, in _get_item_cache
>       values = self._data.get(item)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 4115, in get
>       loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Aidan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 3065, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>
> KeyError: 'y'

So without the 3rd column in the CSV this script executes perfectly. I wanted to include the 3rd column of data for an error bar line. How can I implement the y err bar into my script?

Comment: Using [`plt.errorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save your error bars in a variable as follow:

```
x, y, y_err = x_y[:,0], x_y[:,1], x_y[:,2]
```

and use `plt.errorbar` as

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=y_err, fmt='o', capsize=4, color='black')
```

with the following output. You can customize `errorbar` with further args from this page: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html

[image]

Comment: I made those 2 edits in my script but i am getting the following error:

Comment: see the above edited script and error in my edited post

Comment: The problem seems to be in your file. To plot the figure I posted as an answer, I just copied the data you posted in a csv file and just used the above lines.

Comment: Doesnt my script look like the one you used? or was yours very simple

Comment: I created a `csv` file with the data you provided and did not use the following line `filtered_data = raw_data[~np.isnan(raw_data["y"])]`. I ket everything exactly like you did except I just used `filtered_data = raw_data` where `raw_data` is the data from the `csv` file. It means something is wrong in your line where `isnan` is being called and hence something in your file. To check that, just make a copy of your file and keep only the first 10 data points without any `nan`.